# How can I gather information from each instance of a loop?

Tags: python, loops

Very new to python but I want to store each list generated from each time the loop runs the code again so I can use them in later parts of my code.

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    units = input("Insert Units Sold: ")
    rev = input("Insert Revenue of Sale: ")
    revper = round((int(rev) / int(units)))
    print("Revenue per unit: " + str(revper))
    cogs = (3 * int(units))
    print("Cost of Goods Sold: " + str(cogs))
    profit = (int(rev) - (cogs))
    print("Profit: " + str(profit))
    profitper = round((profit / int(units)))
    print("Profit per Unit: " + str(profitper))

    L1 = [int(units), int(rev), revper, cogs, profit, profitper]
    print("Line " + str(i) + str(L1))
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: I think L1 would make more sense being a dict so you can label each value, e.g.  `L1 = {"Units":int(units),"Revenue":int(rev)} etc. etc.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it:

```
i = 1
myLists = []

while i <= 5:
    units = input("Insert Units Sold: ")
    rev = input("Insert Revenue of Sale: ")
    revper = round((int(rev) / int(units)))
    print("Revenue per unit: " + str(revper))
    cogs = (3 * int(units))
    print("Cost of Goods Sold: " + str(cogs))
    profit = (int(rev) - (cogs))
    print("Profit: " + str(profit))
    profitper = round((profit / int(units)))
    print("Profit per Unit: " + str(profitper))

    L1 = [int(units), int(rev), revper, cogs, profit, profitper]

    # append L1 to myLists
    myLists.append(L1)
    print("Line " + str(i) + str(L1))
    i = i + 1
```

Then you can loop on `myLists` to get each generated list using a `for` loop :

```
for list in myLists:
    # do smth ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `L1` will be overwritten at each loop iteration. But at the end, the last value will be kept in `L1`. If this what you want, then you already have it.

If you want to store all `L1` values, store them in another list:

```py
lst = []
i = 1
while i <= 5:
  ...
  L1 = [int(units), int(rev), revper, cogs, profit, profitper]
  lst.append(L1)
  ...
print(lst)
```

You can of course access each iteration with for instance `lst[2]` for the third instance.

by the way, it’s not in the coding convention to use capitalized letters for a variable. Those are *reserved* for classes and constants. So better use `l1` instead of `L1`.

Hope it helps you and you will improve into your python skills ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can append the list to dictionary and access it by : `all_lists['L1']` or `all_lists['L2']` ...

And TIP for a beginner - use `range` instead of `while` :)

```
all_lists = dict()
for i in range(1, 6):
    units = input("Insert Units Sold: ")
    rev = input("Insert Revenue of Sale: ")
    
    revper = round((int(rev) / int(units)))
    print("Revenue per unit: " + str(revper))
    cogs = (3 * int(units))
    print("Cost of Goods Sold: " + str(cogs))
    profit = (int(rev) - (cogs))
    print("Profit: " + str(profit))
    profitper = round((profit / int(units)))
    print("Profit per Unit: " + str(profitper))
    l = [int(units), int(rev), revper, cogs, profit, profitper]
    print("Line", str(i), str(l))

    all_lists['L{0}'.format(i)] = l

print(all_lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a collection of dicts:

```
from pprint import pprint

dict_dict = {}
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    units = input("Insert Units Sold: ")
    rev = input("Insert Revenue of Sale: ")
    revper = round((int(rev) / int(units)))
    print("Revenue per unit: " + str(revper))
    cogs = (3 * int(units))
    print("Cost of Goods Sold: " + str(cogs))
    profit = (int(rev) - (cogs))
    print("Profit: " + str(profit))
    profitper = round((profit / int(units)))
    print("Profit per Unit: " + str(profitper))

    L1 = {
        'Units sold': int(units),
        'Revenue': int(rev),
        'Revenue per unit': revper,
        'Cost of goods sold': cogs,
        'Profit': profit, 
        'Profit per unit': profitper
   }
   dict_dict[i]=L1
   print("Line " + str(i) + str(L1))
   i = i + 1

pprint(dict_dict)
```